# Android tabHost?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am trying to create a tab host to but I cant seem to make it work, what am i doing wrong? I have setup up createTab() on my onCreate method but it crashes.

I am simply creating a tabhost that holds around 5 tabs. Also I am trying to implement swipe view if anyone knows how to implement it

Main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TabHost tab;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

private void createTab() {
    TabHost.TabSpec tab1Spec = tab.newTabSpec("tab1");
    tab1Spec.setIndicator("TAB 1");
    Intent p = new Intent(this, tab1.class);
    tab1Spec.setContent(p);

    TabHost.TabSpec tab2Spec = tab.newTabSpec("tab2");
    tab2Spec.setIndicator("TAB 2");
    Intent p = new Intent(this, tab2.class);
    tab2Spec.setContent(p);

    tab.addTab(tab1Spec);
    tab.addTab(tab2Spec);
}
```

}

Activity_main xml

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@+id/tab"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
          </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize your tab host , then you've used it in this line which throw a NullPointerException :

```
TabHost.TabSpec tab1Spec = tab.newTabSpec("tab1");
```

before using tab initialize it like :

```
tab = (TabHost)this.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost)
```

Comment: Ive set it as that but it says I still need to have tabhost id as android.r.id.tabhost